# how to set focus to an input within a Bootstrap tab-content when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

on my website done with bootstrap 3.3.6 i have the tabs shown in the image below.
when the page is loaded, the first tab (containing a login-form) is shown by default.
i'd like to set the focus in the input field for the e-mail address (the first one in the image below) when the page is loaded. unfortunately, the following jquery-code seems not to be considered:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtLoginAccountEmail").focus();
});
```

is there anything else to consider when the focus must be set to an input field **which is inside of a tab content?** e.g. any events from the tab or else...

[image]

Comment: Share more code please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the **autofocus** attribute in the input tag.
`<input type="email" autofocus>`
 should work

Answer (score 0):

Simply add active class to first li of tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Guest Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or by jquery

```
$(".nav-tabs li:first-child").addclass('active');
```

Comment: the first <li> has already the active class. it's not a matter of setting the active tab, but setting the focus into a specific input field which is inside of the tab content (which is active)

Answer (score 0):

This is my method if `autofocus` doesn't work

```
  
$(document).on("shown.bs.tab", "button[data-bs-toggle='tab']", function(event) { 
  // event.target // newly activated tab
  // event.relatedTarget // previous active tab
  var activeTab = $('.tab-content .active');
  var focucedInp = $(activeTab).find('input[autofocus="true"]')
  setTimeout(function() { $(focucedInp).focus() }, 200);
});
```